# Access data(set) from popup window with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a page that will open a popup and after something is done on that popup and user close it I want to get data from table / tds. Here is my calling function:

```
function clicked() {
  windowOpener("SiteMap.html");
  popupWin.onbeforeunload = function () {
    var a = $("#drawTable", popupWin.document);
    var tds = $(a).find("td");
    tds.each(function () {
      var p = $(this).data('point');
      if (JSON.stringify(p.values) !== JSON.stringify(point.values)) { //here comes error, to this line
        console.log(p.values);
      }
    })
  };
}
```

.data('point') is created and populated already on that popup page, but still I am getting that $(this).data('point') is undefined. So, is it possible that in that point data is already destroyed? What is your recommendation how to deal with this?

thanks

Comment: Everytime something is changed in the popup have it access `window.parent` to set a global variable. Then when the popup closes you have that data.

Comment: @imvain2 are u saying that I should store those values to global variables instead of storing it in data of td elements?